# Convert dataframe columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I'm trying to plot a `sns.heatmap()` of a list of projects, based on the performance of the projects. Something like that:
[image: Heatmap]

My current dataset looks like this:

```
            Project  Performance
Date                             
2019-03-01        A         37.5
2019-03-01        B        100.0
2019-03-01        C          0.0
2019-03-02        A         99.0
2019-03-02        B         95.0 
2019-03-02        C         97.0
```

I'm trying to convert it to the following format:

```
                  A      B      C
Date           
2019-03-01     37.5  100.0    0.0
2019-03-02     99.0   95.0   97.0
```

I was wondering if I can easily convert my format, but I didn't find an answer.

I'd appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to know what to look for if you're not familiar with database terminology like merging and pivot.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly my main problem:)

Comment: df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Project', values='Performance')
Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html